iptables rules not being applied
I am trying to add iptables rules to prevent all non-cloudflare IP Addresses from accessing my server. I ran the following:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $PORT -s <CloudFlare_IP> -j ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $PORT -s <CloudFlare_IP> -j ACCEPT

Then I attempted to block all other IPs from accessing:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP

However, I am still able to access my website by going to https://Server_IP. Shouldn't the iptables rules prevent this from happening, as accessing the Server_IP directly bypasses the CloudFlare proxies?
Here is my output of iptables -L -v -n:
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 49 packets, 4940 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       131.0.72.0/22        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       172.64.0.0/13        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       104.24.0.0/14        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       104.16.0.0/13        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       162.158.0.0/15       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       198.41.128.0/17      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       197.234.240.0/22     0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       188.114.96.0/20      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       190.93.240.0/20      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       108.162.192.0/18     0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       141.101.64.0/18      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       103.31.4.0/22        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       103.22.200.0/22      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       103.21.244.0/22      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       173.245.48.0/20      0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
13775   14M ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
13775   14M ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  779  147K ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  129 10860 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  129 10860 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  129 10860 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443

Perhaps it has to do with UFW? However, I don't have any rules in UFW that address port 443.
Thanks in advance for taking a look.
NOTE: My nginx server is running from a docker container

Docker makes its own heavy use of firewall, so it doesn't interplay well with firewall set up by hand or with managers like ufw. Also, even if there are no ufw rules that mention port 443, there may be rules that accept for any port, that will stop firewall processing and your drop rule at the bottom is never considered (see 0 in the first column)? Put your rule above it in the form iptables -I INPUT <N> -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP. Also, don't use iptables -L to show your ruleset, because it often hides important information; always use iptables-save (or iptables -S -n) instead.

"so it doesn't interplay well with firewall set up by hand" That's not true at all; the issue is that these rules have been added to the wrong chain. Please see my answer for  a longer explanation.

To apply firewall rules to services running in a Docker container, you need to add the rules to your FORWARD chain, not to the INPUT chain. From the perspective of your host, containerized services are "somewhere else" on the network, which is why traffic traverses the FORWARD chain.
You'll actually want to add your custom rules to the DOCKER_USER chain, which is called by Docker from the FORWARD chain:
# iptables -S FORWARD
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
.
.
.

Putting the rules in DOCKER_USER ensures that they don't get stomped on by Docker's own management of firewall rules.
I'm not familiar with ufw, so I don't know if it's possible to use ufw to add rules to the DOCKER_USER chain. You may end up needing to add these rules using some other mechanism.
